# Longest Common substring breaking issue

Tags: vb.net, string, compare, longest-substring

Hi I have a function that finds the longest common substring between two strings. It works great except it seems to break when it reaches any single quote mark: '

This causes it to not truly find the longest substring sometimes.

Could anyone help me adjust this function so it includes single quotes in the substring? I know it needs to be escaped someplace I'm just not sure where.

Example:
String 1: Hi there this is jeff's dog.
String 2: Hi there this is jeff's dog.

After running the function the longest common substring would be: 
Hi there this is jeff

Edit: seems to also happen with "-" as well.

It will not count anything after the single quote as part of the substring.
Here's is the function:

```
Public Shared Function LongestCommonSubstring(str1 As String, str2 As String, ByRef subStr As String)
    Try
        subStr = String.Empty

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(str1) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(str2) Then
            Return 0
        End If

        Dim num As Integer(,) = New Integer(str1.Length - 1, str2.Length - 1) {}
        Dim maxlen As Integer = 0
        Dim lastSubsBegin As Integer = 0
        Dim subStrBuilder As New StringBuilder()

        For i As Integer = 0 To str1.Length - 1
            For j As Integer = 0 To str2.Length - 1
                If str1(i) <> str2(j) Then
                    num(i, j) = 0
                Else
                    If (i = 0) OrElse (j = 0) Then
                        num(i, j) = 1
                    Else
                        num(i, j) = 1 + num(i - 1, j - 1)
                    End If

                    If num(i, j) > maxlen Then
                        maxlen = num(i, j)

                        Dim thisSubsBegin As Integer = i - num(i, j) + 1

                        If lastSubsBegin = thisSubsBegin Then
                            subStrBuilder.Append(str1(i))
                        Else
                            lastSubsBegin = thisSubsBegin
                            subStrBuilder.Length = 0
                            subStrBuilder.Append(str1.Substring(lastSubsBegin, (i + 1) - lastSubsBegin))
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next

        subStr = subStrBuilder.ToString()

        Return subStr

    Catch e As Exception
        Return ""
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Elaborate on what the issue is... when there is a single quote it stops there? Is there an error? Etc...

Comment: You need more and better examples to helo us understand what you want because  `Hi there this is jeff's dog` is identical to `Hi there this is jeff's dog.` Also explain what * seems to break* means

Comment: how did you check the strings? with a popup or in debug?

Answer (score 1):

I tried it with dotnetfiddle and there it is working with your Code you posted. Please activate your warnings in your project. You have function with no return value and you return an integer or a string. This is not correct. How are you calling your function?

Here is my example I tested for you:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/mVBDQp

Answer (score 1):

Your code works **perfectly** like Regex! As far as I can see, there is really **nothing** wrong with your code.

Here I even tested it under more severe case:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim a As String = ""
    Dim str1 As String = "Hi there this is jeff''s dog.-do you recognize this?? This__)=+ is m((a-@-&&*-ry$#@! <>Hi:;? the[]{}re this|\ is jeff''s dog." 'Try to trick the logic!
    Dim str2 As String = "Hi there this is jeff''s dog. ^^^^This__)=+ is m((a-@-&&*-ry$#@! <>Hi:;? the[]{}re this|\ is jeff''s dog."
    LongestCommonSubstring(str1, str2, a)
    Console.WriteLine(a)
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

Note that I put `'-$@^_)=+&|\{}[]?!;:.<>` all there. Plus I tried to trick your code by giving early result.

But the result is excellent!

[image]

You could probably put more actual samples on the inputs which give you problems. Else, you could possibly describe the environment that you use/deploy your code into. Maybe the problem lies elsewhere and not in the code.

Comment: I do think you are correct. The error must lie elsewhere. I will do some tests and see what I can come up with.

Comment: @ZachJohnson Glad to hear that! Hope you can find the actual issue soon. ;)

Answer (score -1):

The quickest way to solve this would be to use an escape code and replace all the ' with whatever escape code you use

Comment: If you want to compare strings you don't need to replace special characters or escape them.